# Xamarin Forms MVVM Pattern best place to put repeated UI Code

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

We have a xamarin forms app using the MVVM pattern. We have repeated UI logic that gets run whenever any contentView is loaded in the application and just wondering where the best place for this will go. Currently in our legacy application it is written in every control which is incredibly frustrating since if it needs fixing then it needs to be fixed in every separate location. What is the best approach for this type of code.

An example of what I mean is that on initialise of every contentView it runs through security privileges of the current user and hides or shows UI controls on that ContentView depending on what the user is allowed to see. This occurs on every form in the system. This is a simple example but there is plenty.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use ControlTemplate in App.xaml and add the reusable code there and use it wherever required.

Comment: And for C# code you can add a static helper class for the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not put it in a parent class? Derive from ContentView, then have all your relevant controls derive from that. You can do this with pages too. All pages in my latest Xamarin Forms app derive from this:

```
    public abstract class BaseContentPage<T> : ContentPage, IViewFor<T> where T : class, IViewModel
```